# docker image prune is not working for version < 1.13

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-image, pruning

Have tried the following commands, but none of them delete the images.

```
sudo docker images prune --filter "dangling=true"
sudo docker images prune --all
sudo docker images prune -a
sudo docker images prune
```

Output for both the commands:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

Docker version:

```
$ sudo docker version
Client:
Version:      1.12.6
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.4
Git commit:   78d1802
Built:        Tue Jan 10 20:26:30 2017
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
Version:      1.12.6
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.4
Git commit:   78d1802
Built:        Tue Jan 10 20:26:30 2017
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

[Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) suggests this command, but I encountered error

```
$ sudo docker image prune -a
docker: 'image' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'.`
```

Comment: Is it not docker image prune? Not images?

Comment: Just now edited the question with the confirmation. Tried with docker image prune, but got error.

Comment: That looks like quite an old version of docker? Is it CE or EE?

Comment: Right, pretty old version and its CE

Comment: It does not work on Docker < 1.13, and you have 1.12.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [docker image prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) and [API 1.25](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.25/) - For Docker Engine 1.13, the API version is 1.25

> Remove unused images
>
> The client and daemon API must both be at least 1.25 to use this
>   command. Use the docker version command on the client to check your
>   client and daemon API versions.

And you're running *Version: 1.12.6* and *API version: 1.24*, so you need to update your version to be able to run *docker image prune*.

If you don't want to (or can't) upgrade you can use [docker rmi](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/) or [docker image rm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_rm/) which don't have a specified API versions, so I expect both to work.

Comment: `docker rmi` worked. `docker image rm` threw the error as mentioned in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should use `docker image prune --filter "dangling=true"`. It should be `image` instead of `images`.

Also note that in the case of removing dangling images, you don't need to specify a filter, since by default the [prune command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/#extended-description) removes dangling images:

> Remove all dangling images. If -a is specified, will also remove all
>   images not referenced by any container.

Comment: Just now edited the question with the confirmation. Tried with docker image prune, but got error.

Comment: Well said! Ideally docker command should respond with "Did you mean 'docker image prune' when trying to use 'docker images prune'"